# RabbitMQ, Spring AMQP - subscribed non existing queue as exclusive or autodelete

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I have rabbitMQ instance where client is subsribing queue from STOMP web client. If queue is not existing, then is creating with default parameters. I need to keep control of this parameter from server (e. g. as default parameter of new queue) using rabbitMQ server configuration or Spring AMPQ

Comment: You don't need to configure default parameters of new queues, you need to configure the correct Queue object(s) for the queue(s) you are using.

Comment: @OrangeDog the queue is not creating in application - is creating automatically when client subscribing non existing queue